# How to get Lumen response content as string?

Tags: php, api, phpunit, response, lumen

What I'm trying is to get the response content as string from an unit test with Lumen response:

```php
class MovieQueryTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testCanSearch()
    {
        Movie::create([
            'name' => 'Fast & Furious 8',
            'alias' => 'Fast and Furious 8',
            'year' => 2016
        ]);

        $response = $this->post('/graphql', [
            'query' => '{movies(search: "Fast & Furious"){data{name}}}'
        ]);

        $response->getContent(); // Error: Call to undefined method MovieQueryTest::getContent()
        $response->getOriginalContent(); // Error: Call to undefined method MovieQueryTest::getOriginalContent()
        $response->content; // ErrorException: Undefined property: MovieQueryTest::$content
    }
}
```

But I'm unable to figure out how to get the response content.

I don't want to use the Lumen `TestCase->seeJson()` method.

I just need to get the response content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$response` also contains a `response` field on which you need to call `getContent()`, therefore you first need to extract that and then call `getContent()`, so in your code this would become:

```
public function testCanSearch()
    {
        Movie::create([
            'name' => 'Fast & Furious 8',
            'alias' => 'Fast and Furious 8',
            'year' => 2016
        ]);

        $response = $this->post('/graphql', [
            'query' => '{movies(search: "Fast & Furious"){data{name}}}'
        ]);

        $extractedResponse = $response->response; // Extract the response object
        $responseContent = $extractedResponse->getContent(); // Extract the content from the response object

        $responseContent = $response->response->getContent(); // Alternative one-liner

}
```